# How to print the value of "spark.driver.maxResultSize"?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I used `spark-submit` to run my application and set the `conf` as follows:

```
 val conf = new SparkConf(true)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.1.131")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","username")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","password")
  .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4G")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "4G")
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.1.120:7077", "just for fun", conf)
```

I want to know whether my setting `spark.driver.maxResultSize` works fine, so I want to print the value of it, but I don't know how to do it? Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This single line might help you:

`println(conf.get("spark.driver.maxResultSize"))`

However, it would be more appropriate to check the **Spark Properties** table, under the **Environment** tab on **Spark UI**, once your job is submitted.